# Getting NaN in URL even when right variable is passed via router-link

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I am using vue **router-link** to pass **courseId** and **quizId** to **Quiz** Component. When the **Quiz** component in initialized, it gets the **courseId** and **quizId** in the **created()** via `this.$router.params.` The params are obtained in the **first attempt**, but when I **refresh** the page, the **quizId** params is set to **NaN**. Also only the **courseId** is passed in the URL of the component whereas the **quizId** is **NaN**. I don't understand what exactly the problem is. I will post the code below.

**routes**:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: Course,
    name:'ViewCourse'
  },
  {
    path: '/module/:course_id/:module_id',
    component: Module,
    name: 'ViewModule'
  },
  {
    path: '/:course_id/:quiz_id',
    component: Quiz,
    name: 'QuizModule'
  },
  {
    path: '/:course_id/:unit_id/:quiz_id',
    component: QuizInstructions,
    name: 'QuizInstructions'
  }
]
```

**QuizInstructions:**

```
     <router-link :to="{name: 'QuizModule', params: {course_id: courseId, quiz_id: quiz.id}}" class="btn btn-primary">Start Quiz</router-link>
```

**Quiz**:

```
created () {
    const courseId = parseInt(this.$route.params.course_id)
    const quizId = parseInt(this.$route.params.quiz_id)
    // This condition fails as quizId is NaN on page refresh
    if (courseId && quizId){
      this.fetchQuestions(courseId, quizId)
    }
  },
```

Please help me in understanding what I am doing wrong. This used to work before now it is breaking and I am unable to find the issue. Please tell me if more content is required. I have only posted the code which I think is causing the issue.

Thanks.

**Edit**:
Issue resolved. I accidentally did router.push() in one of the vuex action which resulted in setting quizId as NaN. It was because I was pushing wrong undefined variable in the URL.

Comment: I didn't see anything wrong in your code. Please insert this line `console.log(this.$route.params)` in begin of method `created`. I want to see the content of `course_id`

Comment: Hello @GabrielWillemann. Thanks for commenting. I have managed to resolve this issue. I have also edited the question.